# Repository pattern should I use ObjectSet<T> vs IDbSet<T> for base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I'm trying to create a base repository class based off the `MyFinance` example that uses Entity Framework Code first.  I'd like to change it to use just Entity Framework.  The sample uses `IDbSet`, but I have no idea what to change it to for just vanilla Entity Framework.  Maybe `ObjectSet<T>`?  When I use `ObjectSet<T>` I lose some of the methods such as `GetById` so maybe that isn't 100% right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Sample repository base using Entity Framework code first**

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
private MyFinanceContext dataContext;
private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
{
    DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
}

protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
{
    get; private set;
}

protected MyFinanceContext DataContext
{
    get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
}
public virtual void Add(T entity)
{
    dbset.Add(entity);           
}
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    dbset.Attach(entity);
    dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
{
    dbset.Remove(entity);           
}
public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
    foreach (T obj in objects)
        dbset.Remove(obj);
} 
public virtual T GetById(long id)
{
    return dbset.Find(id);
}
public virtual T GetById(string id)
{
    return dbset.Find(id);
}
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return dbset.ToList();
}
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return dbset.Where(where).ToList();
}
public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
    return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
}
```

}

**What I think I should change it to for EntityFramework**

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private MyDBContainer _dataContext;
    private readonly ObjectSet<T> dbset;

    protected BaseRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected MyDBContainer DataContext
    {
        get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DatabaseFactory.DataContext); }
    }
    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.AddObject(entity);
    }
    //public virtual void Update(T entity)
    //{
    //    dbset.Attach(entity);
    //    _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    //}
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.DeleteObject(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (T obj in objects)
            dbset.DeleteObject(obj);
    }
    //public virtual T GetById(long id)
    //{
    //    return dbset.(id);
    //}
    //public virtual T GetById(string id)
    //{
    //    return dbset.Find(id);
    //}
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return dbset.ToList();
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).ToList();
    }
    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }

}
```

Comment: As a side note to what you're doing, I would strongly recommend you not pass around those repositories past your service layer. I would contain all of their usage to things like PeopleService, that could use 1 to many repositories. I also wouldn't inherit from the BaseRepository, that class is good enough to live as a first class citizen. You could then use IOC frameworks like StructureMap to connect them together. I wrote a blog on doing this with NH same concepts apply: http://dotnetchris.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-common-generic-and-extensible-nhiberate-repository-version-2/

Comment: What about your update and GetById? Your Get seems to have that logic. What about update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectSet<T>` is the precursor to `DbSet<T>` and it's associated interface `IDbSet<T>`.  However there isn't as I'm sure you've discovered an `IObjectSet<T>`, but you are correct that you should use `ObjectSet<T>` in place of `DbSet<T>`.